# ConEmu не работает cd

Tags: cmd, conemu

установил http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html

но `cd c:\myfolder` ничего не дает. какие то настройки подкрутить надо?

Comment: Попробуйте `cd /d c:\myfolder`.

Comment: «Спрашивать» нужно шелл! "cd /?" К ConEmu вопрос вообще никак не относится!

Comment: действительно, главное том поменять а потом работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема связана с особенностью работы ОС Windows с текущим каталогом. Всё дело в том, что в Windows есть не только понятие "текущий каталог", но и "текущий каталог диска". Для каждого диска он свой. Команда `cd` меняет *текущий каталог диска*, т.е. если текущий каталог `D:\`, то команда `cd C:\` просто поменяет *текущий каталог диска* `C:`, но *текущий каталог* (отображаемый в командной строке) останется неизменным. Для перехода на другой диск нужно будет в этом случае ввести его имя (`C:`).

Но у `cd` есть параметр `/d`, который "заставляет" её не просто сменить текущий каталог диска, но и перейти на этот диск.